# SonarQube 5.2 and MSBuild Sonar Runner C# - Repository must be set

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1.2

We are using SonarQube 5.2 and latest MSBuild Sonar Runner C# plugin 4.2 but we are getting the error below whenever we are running the Sonar Runner. Please let me know if there is any specific configuration required.

If says "Repository must be set" . I have setup the usual Rules (SonarQube C#). Please share your thoughts and suggest.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to process issues of component 'my:project:CSMAlertSVC/Program.cs'
at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.IntegrateIssuesVisitor.processIssues(IntegrateIssuesVisitor.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.IntegrateIssuesVisitor.visitAny(IntegrateIssuesVisitor.java:59) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.visitAny(TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitNode(VisitorsCrawler.java:97) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:90) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:90) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ExecuteVisitorsStep.execute(ExecuteVisitorsStep.java:51) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:53) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:78) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerRunnableImpl.run(CeWorkerRunnableImpl.java:55) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository must be set
at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.rule.RuleKey.of(RuleKey.java:49) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.TrackerRawInputFactory$RawLazyInput.toIssue(TrackerRawInputFactory.java:116) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.TrackerRawInputFactory$RawLazyInput.loadIssues(TrackerRawInputFactory.java:96) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.issue.tracking.LazyInput.getIssues(LazyInput.java:50) ~[sonar-core-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.issue.tracking.Tracking.<init>(Tracking.java:67) ~[sonar-core-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.issue.tracking.Tracker.track(Tracker.java:37) ~[sonar-core-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.TrackerExecution.track(TrackerExecution.java:41) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.IntegrateIssuesVisitor.processIssues(IntegrateIssuesVisitor.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
... 21 common frames omitted
```